# Haskell - How to iterate to the list and keep the original list instead of just the tail

Tags: haskell, iteration

I'm very new to Haskell.
Below is my function to print all element of the list xs but still want to keep the original xs instead of having the tail for each turn. I don't know how to do that. Is there a way to save/copy the xs before the iteration? Thank you.

```
listElement :: [Int] -> [(Int, Int)]
listElement [] = []
listElement (x:xs) = [(x, length xs)] ++ listElement xs
```

**output:**

```
listElement [1,2,3]
[(1,2),(2,1),(3,0)]
```

**expected:**

```
listElement [1,2,3]
[(1,3),(2,3),(3,3)]
```

Comment: So you want to append (make a tuple) the length of the original (xs) to each element?

Comment: I want to know how to keep the original xs for further process (length is just an example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the general case, you can make a temporary function (`t` in this case), then pass both the original list and the "current tail" as the parameter:

```
t :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [(Int, Int)]
t [] _ = []
t (x:xs) original = [(x, length original)] ++ t xs original

listElement :: [Int] -> [(Int, Int)]
listElement xs = t xs xs

main = print $ listElement [1,2,3]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY2xDsIwDET3fMUNDIkaBmCLVDYGviGKUIeojXADajzk74MRUhWx2Ofns2@ZyjMStcZwDv6eOeB47YQWZSHFBMXwAQ@M0kTr6moxeG1pTnmiL9bVgmKeedmxCRgGMGrZkVKUCt8orjH/xfZpvUmux9@TWpRap5Rlfm9JVgf0Rn@yZ3sJrX0A)

Note that it would be generally better to precompute the length of the list, then just append each of them to each element with a `map`.

In this particular case, it looks like that the compiler can optimize the code and only compute the length once.

```
listElement xs = map (\x -> (x, length xs)) xs
```

```
listElement xs = map (\x -> (x, len)) xs where len = length xs
```